# IO Exception being thrown for unknown reason

Tags: java, ios, java.util.scanner, ioexception

So I added a new scanner called userSettings that give the user a chance to edit some options. But now my program throws an io exception in the starred area down below. I know something is wrong with how I am using the usersettings scanner, but I do not know what.

```
//throw ioexception to handle file issues
public static void Create() throws IOException 
{   
    Scanner userSettings = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to JJJJJ's Task Management  Systems.");
    System.out.print("Would you like to enter settings? yes/any key:");
    String settings = userSettings.next();
    if(settings.equals("yes"));
    {
        settings();
    }
    userSettings.close();

    try
    {   

        File tasklist = new File("bin/tasklist.txt");
        tasklist.createNewFile();

        FileWriter writer = null;

        // creates a FileWriter Object
        if(tasklist.equals(true))
        {
            writer = new FileWriter(tasklist);
        }
        else
        {
            writer = new FileWriter(tasklist, true);
        }

        ListTasks(writer);

        taskInput.close();
        userContinue.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.print("You did something wrong");    
    }
}

public static void ListTasks(FileWriter writer) throws IOException
{
    while(decision.equals("yes"))
    {                   
        System.out.print("Please enter a task: ");
//**************************************************************
        String task = taskInput.nextLine();
//**************************************************************

            // Writes the content to the file
    writer.write(i + " " + task + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));

        System.out.print("Would you like to enter another task? yes/no: ");
        decision = userContinue.nextLine();
        System.out.print(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));

        ++i;
    }

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}

private static void settings() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stud
    System.out.println("Woah not ready yet");
}

}
```

Comment: tasklist.equals(true)... this is wrong. A file can never be true, or false. Btw closing userSettings is a bad idea. This will make it impossible to request more userinput, even if you open a new Scanner.

Comment: It's a common Java convention is for names of Classes to start with the first letter capitalized, methods always start lower case first letter. It's slightly confusing to see method names uppercased.

Comment: Well why don't you print the exception's message and stack trace so you do know why??????

Comment: It never showed an error log, just the text "you did something wrong". However it works now since I moved the scanner.close. I don't understand why this error came about. Does this mean I have to close the scanners after the WHOLE program is finished?